# Adding auth with aws amplify to an existing javascript project

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

So I have working app hosted on aws as static website. Currently it is publicly available, but I wanted to have authentication mechanism, so when user is not currently logged in it will show him login page instead. From following the aws documentation it seems that process requires to have some of additional front end frameworks such as react, vue etc? Is it possible to just use plain javascript to achieve the same results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in components for React, Vue and Angular.

If your app does not use these frameworks, its still possible to use vanilla js.

You need to import

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
```

Then you can use the methods on the Auth class (https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html) independent of the react etc. controls.

For example, to sign up, you would use `Auth.signUp` and to sign in, you would use `Auth.signIn`

The AWS documentation for this is at https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js

Comment: Please, where does that import statement go?